# How to send a request to javascript in AS2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

How can I pass a variable to javascript in actionscript 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ExternalInterface.call()-Method. More information can be found at the Adobe site. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001655.html